# SailsJS on disk development database - what is the format to open it?

Tags: javascript, database, sails.js

While developping a sails application I wish to test the application using some simple values. (So not even an integration test, just to see if it works with a single value).

For development I use the local sails disk based database, under connection.js:

```
localDiskDb: {
  adapter: 'sails-disk'
},
```

and under the models.js file:

```
connection: 'localDiskDb',
```

However this causes a small problem: the database is correctly generated: however I can't manually modify it. If I try to open it in "DB browser for sqlite" I get the popup that the database can't be opened or it is encrypted.

So what format does the disk-based sails database use? And how can I manually modify it to populate it with some simple data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [sails-disk](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-disk) stores data in a flat file in JSON format.

Typically, it is located in the .tmp file of your project and is generated the first time you lift your sails application.

In the example you have provided, the connection to sails-disk is named localDiskDb, so your database will be created as localDiskDb.db.

As the sails-disk stores data in a flat file, you can populate data into the database using any text-editor.

To add data to a specific model, here is an example of what you might do. In this case for a user model:

1 Create the model in your application.

2 Lift the application from the console.

3 Open localDiskDb.db in a text editor, you will see a representation of your model object and an empty array for the model, in this case:

```
"user" : [],
```

4 Populate the model, with dummy data, in JSON format:

```
    "user" : [{
        "username": "john_smith",
        "email": "john_smith@test.com",
        "pass": "$2a$10$NO6gcP6t01ouRxImoDOXdOn5WbyLO2OPh0orgMvSBYVrOCWwpEuHW",
        "id": "91d4c89a-9049-41de-8c9c-34225e6bc86c",
        "createdAt": "2017-12-07T16:57:00.124Z",
        "updatedAt": "2017-12-07T16:57:00.124Z"
    }],
```

5 Upon saving the flat file localDiskDb.db, this user is then available in your application.

One caveat is, as sails-disk is a flat file DB, it doesn't scale and should not be used in anything other than a development/test environment.

Answer (score 1):

I think the default is a file in JSON format. By default it should be saved in your `.tmp/` folder (parallel to `assets/`, `api/` etc)

Try looking for `.tmp/localDiskDb.db`. I was able to manually modify this file in the early days of my first sails project.